# Given that $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{x-2}$ show that $8 \le \int_3^4 f(x)\,dx \le 9$.

Tags: calculus, integration

Consider the function:

$$f : \mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 2\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \hspace{2cm} f(x) = \dfrac{x^2}{x - 2}$$

I have to show that the following statement is true:

$$8 \le \int_3^4 f(x) \, dx \le 9$$

The first thing I did was to find:

$$\int_3^4 f(x) \, dx = \frac{11}{2} + 4 \ln 2$$

I *think* this is correct. The problem I have now is to show the following:

$$8 \le \dfrac{11}{2} + 4 \ln 2 \le 9$$

What I did in order to accomplish this was to first show that the result of the integral is first $\ge 8$ and then that it is $\le 9$. So first I tried to show:

$$\frac{11}{2} + 4 \ln 2 \ge 8$$

$$\frac{11}{2} - 8 + 4 \ln 2 \ge 0$$

After a few calculations I got to the point where I have to show:

$$8 \ln 2 \ge 5$$

$$\ln 2^8 \ge \ln e^5$$

$$ 256 \ge e^5 \tag 1$$

So I have to show that $256 \ge e ^5$. In a similar manner, working with the other part of the inequality (to trying to show that the result of the integral is $\le 9$) I have to show:

$$ 256 \le e^7 \tag 2$$

So I am stuck at proving $(1)$ and $(2)$. If I approximate $e \approx 2.71$ there is no problem, the inequalities are clearly true, but this feels a bit sloppy. Is there another way to prove $(1)$ and $(2)$ (or even the whole given integral inequality from the start) a little more rigorously, not relying on approximations?

Comment: It's good to solve this by integrating, but pretty important also to solve this inequality without integrating as suggested by Henry Lee. It is good practice for analysis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:** What are the minimum and the maximum of $f(x)$ for $x\in[3,4]$?
This is a whole different route, but should be much simpler.

Comment: this is amazing

Answer (score 2):

notice that:

- $f(3)=9$
- $f(4)=8$
  Also by quickly looking at the function in this range it is decreasing, meaning the maximum is 9 and the minimum is 8. Using this, if the function was continuously 8 over the range of one the integral would be 8. using the same logic for 9 you can show the statement is true.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(x)=x+2+\frac{4}{x-2}$, $f^\prime(x)=1-\frac{4}{(x-2)^2}$, so $f^\prime(x)\le0$ on $[3,\,4]$. Since $f$ decreases on $[3,\,4]$ from $f(3)=9$ at $x=3$ to $f(4)=8$ at $x=4$, we can integrate $8\le f(x)\le 9$ on $[3,\,4]$ to get $8\le\int_3^4f(x)dx\le9$.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\frac{x^2}{x-2} \implies f'(x)=\frac{x(x-4)}{(x-2)^2}\le 0, x \in[3,4].$$
$f(x)$ is a decreasing function in the interval. The global maximum is $M=f(3)=9$, its
global minimumm is $m=f(4)=8$. So by MVT, we have
$$m(b-a) \le \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx\le M(b-a) \implies  8 \le \int_{3}^{4} \frac{x^2}{x-2} dx \le 9$$

Answer (score 0):

While the analysis approach as given by others is obviously the "best" method, just following on from what you were doing:

(1) is obviously true because $$3>e\implies 3^5=243>e^5$$
so $$e^5<256$$

(2) is also true because $e>2$ and $$e^7>2^3\times e^4$$

and since $e>2.5$. $$e^4>(2+\frac12)^4>16+4\times8\times\frac12=32$$
Hence $$e^7>8\times32=256$$

Answer (score 0):

$$8 \le \int_3^4 \frac{x^2}{x-2} \, dx \le 9 \text{ ?}$$

\begin{align}
& \overbrace{ \, \frac{x^2}{x-2} = (x+2) + \frac 4 {x-2} \, }^\text{This can be done by long division.} \\[12pt]
& \int_3^4 (x+2)\,dx + \int_3^4 \frac 4 {x-2} \, dx \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac {11} 2 + \int_3^4 \big( \text{something between 2 and 4} \big)\,dx \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac {11} 2 + \big( \text{something between 2 and 4} \big)
\end{align}
This narrows it down to the interval from $7.5$ to $9.5.$

Now let's get a bit subtler: The curve $y = \dfrac 4{x-2}$ is conxex (i.e. concave upward) on the interval $[3,4].$ Therefore the graph lies below the chord that connects the points on the graph at $x=3$ and $x=4.$ The area below the chord is merely the area of a trapezoid, so you don't even need antiderivatives. It is $3.$ So the integral we seek is less than $8.5.$ But covexity also implies the graph is above the two tangent lines at $x=3$ and $x=4.$ Look at where those two tangent lines meet and you need the areas of two trapezoids. This gives you a lower bound.

Answer (score 0):

A very quick way to show this is by finding the area under the curve in the interval from 3 to 4

The plot of $ f(x) $ looks like this- [here is the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3myEy.png).
From the plot it's very clear that area under the curve in $ [3, 4] $ is bounded between 8 and 9

Also, this function can be re-written as:

$$
f(x)=\frac{x^{2}}{x-2} = \frac{x^{2}-4+4}{x-2}= \frac{x^{2}-4}{x-2} + \frac{4}{x-2} \
=x+2+ \frac{4}{x-2}$$

For the values of $ f(x) $ in $ [3,4], f(3)=5+4=9 $ and $ f(4)= 6+2=8$,  function integral in the range $[3,4]$ is calculated as

$$\begin{aligned}
f(x)&=\frac{x^{2}}{x-2}\\
&= \frac{x^{2}-4+4}{x-2}\\
&= \frac{x^{2}-4}{x-2} + \frac{4}{x-2}\\
&=x+2+ \frac{4}{x-2}\end{aligned}$$

$$\begin{aligned}
&\int_{3}^{4} x+2+ \frac{4}{x-2}\\
=& \left[\frac{x^{2}}{2}+2x+4\ln(x-2)\right]_3^4\\
=& \left[\frac{4^{2}}{2}+8+4\ln2\right]-\left[\frac{3^{2}}{2}+6+0\right] \\=& 16+ 4\ln2-4.5-6 \\
=& 5.5+4\ln2 (\because \ln2\approx .69)\\ 
\approx& 8.3
\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 0):

use the fact that $m(b-a)\leq \int_a^b f(x)dx\leq M(b-a$).
 where $m,M $ be the global maximum and minimum of of $f$ on $[a,b]$, in this case $m=f(4), M=f(3)$, since the funtion is decrasing on the specified interval, which can easily be seen by first derivative test.